# Luigi/SQLite: How to update database after initial load?

Tags: python, sqlite, etl, luigi

I'm loading data into an SQLite database via Luigi with the following code:

```
class LoadData(luigi.Task):   
    
    def requires(self):
        return TransformData()
        
    def run(self):
        with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO prod SELECT * FROM staging;")
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('database.db')
```

This works, but when I want to update or insert new data, **the task doesn't execute because Luigi considers it complete (`database.db` already exists)**.

Maybe I didn't understand the good use of LocalTarget. What is the right way to approach this?

///EDIT: My question applies to the example given on [this page](https://kapernikov.com/using-luigi-to-power-a-reporting-pipeline/) (code for `le_create_db.py`). How do you solve updates and inserts in that example?

///EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960735/how-to-continously-update-target-file-using-luigi) about appending to a file is similar, but the solution using marker files does not work because sqla expects an `SQLAlchemyTarget` output. Are there any other answers, specifically about appending to a database?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a mock file:
http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/building-luigi-task-pipeline.html

In each execution you will be creating a new file.

Another solution could be using the strategy of creating a marker table inside the db, for example: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.contrib.postgres.html#luigi.contrib.postgres.PostgresTarget

Comment: I read that mock files are recommended during development. What disadvantages for using it in production?

Comment: Let's image you have 3 dependant tasks in production working with mock files. The last task fails, you will need to start from the begining.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it by overriding the `complete` method to simply return `False`:

```py
def complete(self):
    return False
```

Now the task is re-run every time, even if database file is present.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options, in general:

- update just once (only if db file does not exist)
- update everytime (override `complete` and always return `False`)
- customize what `complete` means (e.g. decide on the recency last snapshot in the database, if a new one should be done)

Here are all three variants side by side in a single snippet: https://gist.github.com/miku/fb53af7576bc3e5dd1df3ad627db4d07

Only once:

```py
def output(self):
    # (1) will run only once
    return luigi.LocalTarget(dbfile)
```

Always:

```py
def complete(self):
    # (2) will run every time the task is called
    return False
```

Custom logic:

```py
def complete(self):
    # (3) custom logic, e.g. backoff
    # if the last snapshot happened recently
    with sqlite3.connect(dbfile) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            """
           select strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%s', t)
           from dummy
           order by t desc
           limit 1
            """
        )
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None:
            return False
        diff_s = row[0] # 2023-09-14 09:25:33

    return int(diff_s) < 10
```